# When all Illustrator layers are turned off, is the canvas outside the art board always white?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, artboard, creative-cloud, canvas

I am not sure if this was always the case but it seems new to me, when I hide all layers in an Illustrator CC 2020 document, the canvas outside the art board is white ( kind of like *outline* )

I have toggled GPU Preview which solves it but as soon as I turn the layer on & off again , it reverts to white.

I have tried **Overprint Preview**, I have tried **View > Hide / Show Art boards**

There is a chance it has always been like this, but in the years hiding all layers , I have never noticed it. I feel that I may have hit a shortcut that did some obscure action which I cannot revert.

Attached is a screen shot of a new document with a single layer **On & then Off**

**UI Interface** is not the issue , nor is **Outline**.

Appreciate any help , thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate this issue in AI CC 2018. Perhaps it's a bug, or a graphics card glitch. Tech support is generally off-topic here because such questions are difficult to answer without access to your computer/setup. Probably better to contact Adobe directly for support.

Answer (score 1):

It's done this for years in various versions.

CS6 and earlier does this, and CC versions will if you are using the CPU preview.

Since anything prior to CC used the CPU preview, I assume that's the cause. I can't speculate as to *why* it happens, but I can confirm it does happen if the CPU preview is in use.

I don't honestly know why it matters much. It's rare that a user *actually* hides **all** layers. I don't understand what purpose hiding all layers, and being concerned about this, would serve.

Comment: Just checked, you are right. It happens if you are on CPU preview, and presumably if the graphics card is not recognised/drivers are too old, this will be the default view when you switch off all layers.